# Trouble with making a plot with R data of multiple categories

Tags: r, plot

I am fairly new to R, and I'm attempting to plot some data into R. But I am not certain what the issue is, whether or not I had formatted the data wrong when putting it into R, or my code, in general, I am confused. I am trying to make a plot of data that was collected from different species of animals and their occurrences. However, I'm not entirely sure about the code that needs to be used to have multiple points on the X-axis for each species and only the transects on the y-axis.

I have tried a line of code from memory, but it does not seem to be working.

```
plot(sb$Site~sb$AMKE$BAEA$FEHA$GOEA$MERL$NOHA$PRFA$RTHA$SWHA,
  ylim=c(0,22), xlab= "# of individuals", ylab="Site/Transect",
  type="b", col="cornflowerblue")
```

I'm not entirely sure if my CSV file is properly formatted and that is why I am having trouble making this plot. I am trying to make the Site number the Y-axis, and the number of individuals for each group on the x-axis

Here is the data set that I am working with:

[image]

I am hoping to get a revised code to help me out, or simply point me in the right direction, as I know its most likely a simple fix.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: `sb$AMKE$BAEA$FEHA$GOEA$MERL$NOHA$PRFA$RTHA$SWHA` is not valid R syntax. What exactly are you trying to plot?